# PHP file not running in AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My AJAX function is not running my PHP script.  I have a similar function for my signup and it is working without any issues.  The AJAX function runs to the end of the done call but the first line in the PHP file that creates a cookie does not run.

I have outputted the data(result) to console and that all looks good.  No errors come up and I have enabled PHP errors on my server which I have full control over.  The server is fine as this exact approach was used for the sign-up portion of the website and it works.

**JQuery**

```
$('#login-form').on("submit", function(e){
    var dataString = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(dataString);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "bin/login.php",
        data: dataString
    }).done(function (result, status, xhr) {
            // Display message back to the user here.
            window.location.replace('./app/');
            console.log("Login Completed!");
        }).fail(function (result) {
            // TASK: Add a visual element on the page for errors.
            if (result.status == 522){
                alert("Email not verified!");
            } else if (result.status == 523){
                alert("Password was incorrect!");
            } else if (result.status == 524) {
                alert("User account not found!");
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    setcookie("TestCookie", "login.php", none, "/");
    if (array_key_exists('emailAddress', $_POST) && array_key_exists('password', $_POST)){
        $emailAddress = $_POST["emailAddress"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        // Connect to the database with this standard connect PHP script.
        include('connectDB.php');
        // Check the link was established.
        if (!mysqli_connect_error()) {
            $sqlget = "SELECT id, emailAddress, userPassword, userRole, emailVerified FROM users WHERE emailAddress=\"$emailAddress\"";
            $sqldata = mysqli_query($dbconn, $sqlget);
            
            if (mysqli_num_rows($sqldata) == 1){                
                // One user was found.
                $userInfo = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata);                
                setcookie("Account", "found", none, "/");
                if ((password_verify($password, $userInfo["userPassword"])) {   
                    setcookie("Password", "OK", none, "/");
                    if ($userInfo["emailVerified"] == true) {
                        setcookie("loginId", $userInfo["id"], none, "/");
                    } else {
                        // Email was not verified.
                        header('HTTP/1.1 522 Email Not Verified');
                        header('Conent-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
                        die(json_encode($result));                                    
                    }                    
                } else {
                    // Password verification failed.
                    header('HTTP/1.1 523 Password verification Failed');
                    header('Conent-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
                    die(json_encode($result));   
                }
            } else {
                // No user found in the system
                header('HTTP/1.1 524 User not Found');
                header('Conent-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
                die(json_encode($result));    
            }
        } else {
            // Place code to tell the user there was an internal DB error.
            // Possibly a standard error message.  Lets not scare the user.        
            header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
            header('Conent-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
            die(json_encode($result));
        }
    }    
?>
```

Comment: what is `none` in your `setcookie("TestCookie", "login.php", none, "/");`

Comment: Instead of relying on javascript to read the cookie, I would just rely on the PHP to verify if they are logged in etc and return that error message back to Javascript.

Comment: change`none` to zero (0) if you dont want the cookie to expire.

Comment: @imvain2 Yea that is a better approach.  Thanks for bringing that to my attention.  Still doesn't help with why the PHP file is not running in the first place though.

Comment: @Kisaragi  Thanks.  I did see a message that none was depreciated.  I had a note to look into that once I got this problem solved.  Thanks for saving me time.  I changed that but code still doesn't run.

Comment: @TimNeufeld, when you refresh the page and look at cookies, `TestCookie` doesn't exist anywhere?

Comment: @imvain2 Nope.  I opened chrome dev tools and that TestCookie does not come up.

Comment: @TimNeufeld, even after changing none to 0?

Comment: @imvain2 Yes.  The PHP script doesn't run at all so this would not fix the issue, but I did change it and tested.  Same issue.

Comment: In the console, when you go to run the ajax, is there any 404 errors for `bin/login.php`?

Comment: @imvain2 No.  I just thought maybe that it was not finding the file, so I changed that to a nonexistent file and I got an error.  Changed it back and no error so it is seeing the file is there.

Comment: I figured it out.  There was one too many brackets on line 18.

Change it to if (password_verify($password, $userInfo["userPassword"])) {

Got love those syntax errors.

Comment: @Dharman Thank you.  I know that there is a risk of injections but it is not live.  I was going to change that before go-live.

Comment: While you are at it I would also recommend using PDO instead of mysqli. It is easier. However, you really should use some kind of database abstraction library.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  I had one too many brackets on line 18.  I changed the line to the following and the PHP script ran.

```
if (password_verify($password, $userInfo["userPassword"])) {
    if ($userInfo["emailVerified"] == true) {
        setcookie("loginId", $userInfo["id"], 0, "/");
    } else {
        // Email was not verified.
        header('HTTP/1.1 522 Email Not Verified');
        header('Conent-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        die(json_encode($result));                                    
    }                    
} else {
    // Password verification failed.
    header('HTTP/1.1 523 Password verification Failed');
    header('Conent-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    die(json_encode($result));   
}
```